# GSON exclude fields with custom annotation

Tags: java, gson

We have a jsp file with generic page content for admin purpose.

In this we have to hide audit columns, we have used annotation to specify the columns to show in search result, and we have one custom class that filters special character fields.

```
 Gson gson = gsonBuilder.registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(Object.class,
        new CustomJsonSerializer())
        .serializeNulls()
        .setExclusionStrategies(new AdminTableSearchJsonStrategy())
        .create();
```

With the above code special character filters but hiding audit columns not working.

If we remove **CustomJsonSerializer** class then audit column exclusive working, but we want these two to be there, please advice this in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created an empty interface extends **ExclusionStrategy** and **JsonSerializer** and this interface implements in **AdminTableSearchJsonStrategy** now this class having both functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Expose` Annotation for that field that you want to Include and build using `GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()`

Comment: Thank you, We have two screens one for search and another for add & edit, some of audit column will be shown in add edit screens, so we can't use expose in that case, that's the reason we choose java annotations to specify the field nature.

Comment: In that case you have to use two seperate models. With one exposed for one screen and other without exposed.

Comment: We have to go through code review, we have more than 20+ admin screens each one if i create two models, I will get out of the premises.